# Why is it called "bicarbonate"?

Tags: nomenclature, hydrocarbons

I'm helping to teach some kids about the baking soda/vinegar reaction, and was hoping to point out how the chemical names are just a direct translation of the chemical formula.

However I was surprised to find there is no "2" in the formula for "sodium **bi**carbonate", $\ce{NaHCO3}$.

Can someone explain where the "bi" comes in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate#Nomenclature)

> The prefix bi in bicarbonate comes from an outdated naming system and is based on the observation that there is twice as much carbonate ($\ce{CO3}$) per sodium in sodium bicarbonate ($\ce{NaHCO3}$) as there is in sodium carbonate ($\ce{Na2CO3}$).

The IUPAC name for it agrees with its chemical formula: **sodium hydrogen carbonate**.